# Restlet DigestAuthenticator hashed local secret

Tags: restlet, digest-authentication

I am trying to use a `DigestAuthenticator` to secure some parts of an API I am creating using Restlet. In all of the examples, the `DigestAuthenticator` expects to wrap a `LocalVerifier` that will return the local secret in plain text. Obviously, I do not want to store all of my users' passwords in plain text. How can I use HTTP Digest with Restlet while not providing the local secret in plain text?

I have written a `LocalVerifier` that uses the identifer to query a db and retrieve a sha1'd password, but it doesn't work unless my `Verifier` returns the password in plain text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I hashed all the passwords on the server side in the database, and I hashed the password on the client side before it was hashed by http digest. Seems like a more secure solution to me anyway.

Comment: Thx for your Q&A. After reading this, I debugged the DigestAuthentication looking for a place where I could override some method to encode the secret so it would match the encoded hash in my user database. The whole point of digest auth however is that the secret is not transmitted plain! So your solution of pre-encoding with whatever hash you used really is the only one. Since my client is distributed and could probably be decompiled, I am not sure I want to give away my hash. So digest is not a solution for me.

Comment: Hi Finbarr, this is an issue for me as well. Unfortunately restlet is both my client and server. That makes it a tat difficult to hash the password before verifying. I looked through the code and it seems that DigestVerifier has logic to hash the secret with MD5. However, this requires the algorithm and the wrappedAlgorithm to be set. The wrappedAlgorithm is easy, but the algorithm is not easy to set. I have extended DigestAuthenticator to set the algorithm, but it is not working. Was your trick simply to use a different client or did you work withing restlet? Thanks